# Display keybindings typed in a buffer

Tags: commands, help, keystrokes, logging

On [this video stream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4z2Ywregkig&feature=emb_logo), the window on right displays the keybindings typed with its corresponding command bound.
Is there any package that does that, or a way to achieve it?

Comment: did my expanded answer work for you in Org and cc-mode?

Answer (score 4):

Yes!  This is `command-log-mode` which can be installed from Melpa.

You have to add the function to whatever modes you want to record, like

```lisp
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'command-log-mode)
```

Then, to invoke the log window as shown in the video

```
M-x clm/open-command-log-buffer
```

Open a Python file (in my example) and start manipulating the code to see your actions in the command log buffer.

There is also `M-x global-command-log-mode` to capture all (or most) interactions across modes.

Comment: Interesting... I thought it was something not dependent on any mode, so I could get logs for every single Emacs command... And for some reason, I am able to run it with python-mode, but not with org-mode or cc-mode. Strange. I probably miss something.

Comment: Sorry - I usually use it with just one or two modes.  Updated my answer, which works well for Org Mode also!

Answer (score 2):

> *Is there any package that does that, or a way to achieve it?*

One such package is [Show Key](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowKey) (code: [`showkey.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/showkey.el)).

Global minor mode **`showkey-log-mode`** keeps a log of such events, in a separate frame. It's refreshed with each new event, and it's kept on top of other frames without stealing the input focus. Various user options control what events get logged, etc.